# How can I create a privately-settable read-only struct (such as Size) in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, constants, structure, readonly

Not sure if this can be done, but I need to calculate and store a size in a base class, then expose that result as read-only to subclasses.  Making the Size itself readonly is easy by hiding it behind a property with a protected getter and a private setter, like this...

```
private Size _someSize;
protected Size SomeSize
{
    get{ return _someSize; }
    private set{ _someSize = value; }
}
```

Then from within the base class, I can set it like this...

```
SomeSize = new Size(23.0, 14.7);
```

...but I can't do that from a subclass class because the setter is private to the base class.

However, I also don't want the subclass to be able to modify the members of the Size structure either.

### Update

In the subclass, if you try and compile this...

```
SomeSize.Width = 17.0;
```

...you will get the error 'Cannot modify the return value of SomeSize because it is not a variable' so that does protect the value in the base class as I had hoped.

Still, if someone can figure out how to make the getter return a *true* read-only structure (if such a thing is even possible, which I doubt), I'll give you the answer. Granted, that wasn't actually needed for this problem, but that would still be a good thing to know if it can be done.

Comment: Is the class Size also implemented by you?

Comment: Maybe use the base.new (base class constructor) (don't know the c# syntax exactly...)

Comment: No. It's part of the .NET framework.  I know I can mark a variable with the 'readonly' attribute to do just that, but then I can't use it as a backing for the getter/setter because I can't change it.

Comment: Do you set the value in the constructor only, or can it be set/updated by a method call?

Comment: It can (and is) set multiple times in the base class.  I just don't want the subclasses to be able to touch it.  Use it, sure.  Not change it.  The base class should have free-reign.  I'm wondering if there's any way to make the property accessors return a readonly or a const.  Of course I could always just create a new instance on every 'Get' but that's smelly to me.

Comment: Did you test it?  Size is a structure (value type), not a class (reference type), so the property getter should be returning a copy of the internal size, not a reference to it.  Therefore, when a sub class changes the Width property of the size that is returned by the property, it shouldn't be touching the private _someSize.  Unless I'm wrong....

Comment: Are you sure inheritance is the correct approach? It sounds like it is not the correct design for this problem. Perhaps delegation makes more sense and either completely break the inheritance relationship or extract the problem method into its own class.

Comment: Actually, not sure why I didn't try this, but in the subclass, I just tried doing SomeSize.Width = 17; and it did fail compilation, so maybe it does do what I want! I got the error that I can't set the member because SomeSize is not a variable!

Comment: I believe you get that error because _Size_ is a struct rather than a reference type.

Comment: Exactly.  I was trying to make the struct const or readonly, but because the compiler blocks that operation in the first place, it isn't actually needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not have tried to compile it, because what you have proposed already meets your needs.  The `Size` type is a `structure` (value type), not a `class` (reference type), so the property getter will return a copy of the value stored in _someSize, not a reference to it. Therefore, if a sub class actually tried to change the `SomeSize.Width` property, it wouldn't actually be touching the private _someSize variable.  It would just be changing the copy of that value that was returned.  The compiler, however, recognizes that doing so is invalid, therefore, it won't even let the following line compile:

```
SomeSize.Width = 17.0;
```

The only way you could change the value and still get it to compile would be like this:

```
Size temp = SomeSize;
temp.Width = 17.0;
```

However, like I said, since that's just a copy of the value, it won't actually change the value of the `SomeSize` property--it will only change the value of `temp`.

If, however, the `Size` type was a class, you could still accomplish the same kind of protection by simply returning a clone of the object rather than a reference to the original object.  For instance, if `Size`, was actually a class that looked like this:

```
public class MySize
{
    public MySize(float height, float width)
    {
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
    }

    public float Height { get; set; }
    public float Width { get; set; }

    public MySize GetCopy()
    {
        return (MySize)MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Even though it's properties are not read-only, you could still make a pseudo read-only property out of it like this:

```
private MySize _someSize;
protected MySize SomeSize
{
    get { return _someSize.GetCopy(); }
    private set { _someSize = value; }
}
```

However, if you really want the properties of the returned object to be read-only, the only way to do that is to implement your own read-only version of the original type.  For instance, the `List<T>` type supports the ability to get a read-only version of itself so that you can use that for read-only list properties.  Because `List<T>` has that built-in functionality, you can easily do something like this:

```
private List<string> _list = new List<string>();
public ReadOnlyCollection<string> List
{
    get { return _list.AsReadOnly(); }
}
```

However, as you can see, the `AsReadOnly` method doesn't return a `List<T>` object.  It instead returns a `ReadOnlyCollection` object which is a whole new type that is custom made as a read-only version of the list.  So, in other words, the only way to truly make a read-only `Size` property would be to create your own `ReadOnlySize` type, like this:

```
public struct ReadOnlySize
{
    public ReadOnlySize(Size size)
    {
        _size = size;
    }

    private Size _size;

    public float Height 
    {
        get { return  _size.Height; } 
    }

    public float Width
    {
        get { return _size.Width; }
    }
}
```

And then you could make your read-only property like this:

```
private Size _someSize;
public ReadOnlySize SomeSize
{
    get { return new ReadOnlySize(_someSize); }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I just said in my update, but since you put it in an answer, I'll give it to you.  Also @Steven, I would advise against the 'snarky' remarks though. (i.e. 'Apparently...')  People make mistakes and in my code I was messing with the return value after it had been stored and was trying to make that a readonly or a const.  I hadn't considered the effects/protection of someone trying to set it directly on the getter, which the compiler blocks, thus giving me what I was originally seeking, just from a different vector.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I honestly didn't mean it in a snarky way at all, but I can see now how you would have taken it that way.  Hopefully my edited answer now more accurately relays my intended meaning.  I had already voted your question up because I thought it was a good question.

Comment: N/P. It's all good! :)  BTW, I'm (temporarily) removing the 'accepted state' since technically that didn't give me the const/readonly-ness I was hoping for, although it did solve our particular needs.  Still, I want to see if there's any way for a function to return a true read-only struct, so I want this to show up in the 'unanswered' category.  If no one chimes in with a solution, or it's proven there isn't one, I'll re-accept this.  Just wanted you to know what's going on and why I removed it.

Comment: Just copying my comment from above: If I define a variable called 'foo' of type Size with the readonly attribute, I can set 'foo' in a constructor, but not after. That's understood. However, in addition to the variable being read-only, the members of the struct are also now read-only. The compiler will not let you set the width. There is some protection on that variable and its members. I was trying to see if the protection is on the address of the struct, or something on the struct itself that could be passed around. (I think it's the former which means my question is actually invalid.)

Comment: It's true that the compiler recognizes that error and stops you from changing one of the sub-properties of a read-only property that is of a value type, but it does not stop you from doing that on a property that is of a reference type.  For instance, if you changed it to a `readonly MySize` property, then it would allow you to change the height or width outside of the constructor.

Comment: I understand that, but again, I am talking about a value type which is what a struct is.  Put a different way, my question is is it possible to return a readonly struct from a function or property getter.  My guess at this point is no since it's not the data, but the variable the 'readonly' protects.  Again, a guess, but all tests seem to support that theory.

Comment: BTW, I'm marking yours as accepted again since it doesn't look like there's any way to return a read-only structure from a function. Note: I'm not talking about an instance vs. a copy.  I'm talking about whichever is on the way out, there's no way to mark it as read-only.  Then again, the compiler will protect against setting a field directly on the getter, and even if it was a readonly struct, you can simply assigning it to another struct which wouldn't be read-only so I guess there's actually no need to do this anyway (hence you again getting the answer.)  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I understand your question.  My answer is no.  There is no way to take an existing type, whether it be a struct or a class, and, without altering the type itself, make an object of that type be read-only.  You can make variables be read-only, and the compiler can enforce that, but you can''t make an object read-only unless you alter the code in the class or struct to make it so.

Answer (score 0):

One of the major limitations of structure types in .net languages is that while the fields of a writable struct-type storage location (variable, field, parameter, array slot, etc.) are themselves writable storage locations (and if they are struct types, their fields are likewise writable storage locations), such access only works with struct type *storage locations*, and there is no means via which any type other than `System.Array` can expose a *property* that works like a storage location.

It is possible for a class to expose a privately-held storage location as a storage location under controlled circumstances, if it offers a method which can pass that storage location as a `ref` parameter to a supplied callback.

For example:

```
public delegate void ActByRef<T1>(ref T1 p1);
public delegate void ActByRef<T1,T2>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2);
public delegate void ActByRef<T1,T2,T3>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2, ref T3 p3);

public void ActOnSize(ActByRef proc) 
  { proc( ref _someSize); }
public void ActOnSize<XT1>(ActByRef proc, ref XT1 xp1) 
  { proc( ref _someSize, ref xp1); }
public void ActOnSize<XT1,XT2>(ActByRef proc, ref XT1 xp1, ref XT2 xp2)
  { proc( ref _someSize, ref xp1, ref xp2); }
```

If one wished to add 5 to the width of a something which exposed such a method, one could then use

```
thing.ActOnSize((ref Size sz) => sz.Width += 5);
```

If one had a local variable 'HeightAdder', and one wished to add that to the object's height, one could use

```
thing.ActOnSize((ref Size sz, ref int adder) =>
  sz.Height += adder, ref HeightAdder);
```

Note that because the lambda expression as written would not capture any local variables, it could be evaluated as a static delegate (if the delegate had added `HeightAdder`, rather than `ref` parameter `adder` to the height, that would have required generating a closure to hold `HeightAdder` each time it entered scope, and would have required generating a delegate each time the method call is executed; passing the amount as a `ref` parameter avoids that overhead).

A similar approach could be used by a class similar to `List<T>` or `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` to allow a callback method to act directly on a list slot or dictionary entry, if the access method includes a parameter for the index or key.

One nice feature of this approach is that it allows collections to provide for styles of concurrent access that are otherwise difficult.  If the things in the collection are of a type which can be used with `Interlocked` methods (or are exposed-structure types whose fields are usable with such methods), client code may use such methods to perform thread-safe atomic operations on the underlying data.  If the things in a collection are not of such a type, the collection may be able to implement locking somewhat more safely than would be possible with other approaches.  For example, a `ConcurrentIndexedSet<T>` might have a family of `ActOnItem(int item, int timeout, ActByRef<T> proc)`; methods which will invoke `proc` on an item within a lock (trusting that the client-supplied `proc` can be trusted to return in a reasonable timeframe).  While such code couldn't guard against the possibility of `proc` getting deadlocked or otherwise waylaid, it could ensure that the lock will get released before returning control to the calling code.

Comment: If I define a variable called 'foo' of type Size with the readonly attribute, I can set 'foo' in a constructor, but not after. That's understood. However, in addition to the variable being read-only, the members of the struct are also now read-only.  The compiler will not let you set the width.  There is some protection on that variable *and* its members.  I was trying to see if the protection is on the address of the struct, or something on the struct itself that can be passed around.  (I think it's the former which means my question is actually invalid.)

Comment: If a struct is only exposed as a read-only property, then there will be no mechanism via which the fields of the struct can change.  Note that it is not necessary for the struct type itself to be "immutable" to achieve this; a struct with exposed fields will likewise be unmodifiable under the same circumstances.  Note also that if the struct encapsulates the state of one or more outside objects to which it holds a reference, it's possible that the state of those objects (and thus the effective state of the struct) could change.

Comment: It all boils down to the same thing I think: there's no way to return a read-only struct from a function.  To be clear, I'm not talking about returning the same instance vs. a copy.   I'm saying whichever struct is returned, there's no way to mark it as readonly on the way out.

Comment: @MarqueIV: *Any* struct returned by a function will be read-only unless or until its value is stored somewhere else.  If the value is stored in a mutable storage location, it will--like all structures stored in mutable storage locations--be mutable, but such mutation will only affect the instance that was stored in that mutable location, and not affect any instance stored anywhere else in the universe.

Comment: Actually, your comment 'Any struct returned ... will be read-only' isn't technically accurate because the structure itself *is* mutable. The compiler just blocks your access to it because every getter call returns a new instance, so without that block, if you set width, then height directly on the getter, you'd actually be setting it on two different copies, neither of which you have access to afterwards.  But the type itself isn't readonly. All in all, from what I gather, only a variable can be readonly as a compiler feature, not the struct it points to itself.  Still, was fun learning this.

Comment: @MarqueIV: In C++, struct member functions must declare whether they will modify the underlying struct; those which declare themselves as modifying the struct cannot be invoked upon function return values; those which do not declare themselves as modifying the struct can be so invoked, but are not allowed to modify the struct (except via const-casting which would, if C# had similar rules, require an "unsafe" declaration).  Since C# and .net do not provide for such declarations, struct methods that are invoked on read-only struct values are given temporary struct instances to act upon.

Comment: @MarqueIV: It is true that struct methods can do whatever they want with those temporary instances, but such changes will not affect any read-only struct instance or value which is required to still exist afterward (in some cases where the scope of one instance ends precisely where the scope of another begins, a compiler may reuse the same storage location, but it logically represents a distinct instance).

Comment: Not sure why you're talking about struct member functions.  I was talking about pure structures with exposed members that are returned from a function elsewhere, not a member function.  Still, you're otherwise arguing basically the same thing I said except I was making the distinction on where the readonly was enforced, which is on the variable and only at compile time.  We're on the same page.

Comment: @MarqueIV: The only situation in which a struct returned by a function might arguably be regarded as mutable is when it is passed to a struct member function which mutates it.  If a function's return value is copied to a variable and that is modified, the variable is by definition a separate struct instance; the fact that the instance held in that variable is mutable says nothing about whether the instance that was returned is mutable.

Comment: Sorry, @Supercat, but I have to call you on that.  Dig deep in the IL and you will see nothing protecting the struct that is returned from a function.  I'm not talking about copying to a new variable (as you keep bringing up for some reason), I'm talking about the internals of the function itself and the struct copy created within which is returned, and normally assigned to a variable.  It is fully mutable. (if it weren't, that would actually be the mechanism I was looking for.) (continued...)

Comment: The compiler blocks you from acting with dot-syntax directly on the function because you would be modifying the internally created copy, with no way to access it afterwards. Any subsequent actions against that function (including assigning it to another variable) would again create a new copy, meaning the one you just modified would have dropped off the stack.  That's why the compiler blocks that.  In all cases, the original, internal one that was copied from of course remains unchanged, but it too is technically mutable (unless marked read-only internally)

Comment: @MarqueIV: At the IL level, the calling function puts the return value into a certain area of "memory" (RAM or registers), which the caller is free to do with as it will.  If the caller has a statement `var foo = myThing.SomeFunction()`, the compiler may decide that if it reuses that memory to hold `foo`, it won't actually have to copy anything, but at that point, the memory no longer represents the instance returned by the function, but the instance represented by `foo`.  Semantically, the instance returned by the function no longer exists.  To look at it another way...

Comment: @MarqueIV: Suppose a method says `int Biz=23;` and then at some point past the last use of `Biz`, it says `int Boz=56;`.  The compiler may decide that the same memory should be used to hold `Boz` as was used to hold `Biz`, so the second declaration would cause that memory location to hold 56.  Does that mutate `Biz`?  No it doesn't, because `Biz` no longer exists.  The runtime doesn't care whether the code is setting Biz to 56 or is instead reusing the space to hold `Boz`, provided the location doesn't go from holding an object reference to holding a value type, nor vice versa.

Comment: @MarqueIV: More concrete example: suppose I write `myVar = foo()+6;` and `foo()` returns the `int` value 23.  When `foo` returns, EAX holds the return value (23).  If the compiler generates `ADD EAX,23 / MOV [myVar],EAX`, then after the `ADD` instruction executes, the value in EAX will have changed because *it will no longer hold the return value*; it will hold the result of a temporary subexpression.  That the function returned 23 is a fact.  A microsecond later there may be no evidence of that fact, but that wouldn't change the fact that the value returned by the function was 23.

Comment: This is a pointless conversation. Your comment 'Semantically, the instance returned by the function no longer exists.' and you talking about variables dropping out of scope is *EXACTLY* what I keep saying (i.e. if you don't store the return value, the memory used to hold the internal copy will no longer be accessible by the caller post-call, and thus will be marked as available since nothing else is pointing to it, which is why the compiler blocks acting on the function), yet for some reason you keep discussing 'Variables 101'.  You're still completely missing my point.  I'm out.